# How to enable PoE on HP ProCurve 2650

Tags: ethernet, hp-procurve, cli, power-over-ethernet

I own a Hewlett-Pacard **ProCurve 2650** switch. I want to switch on power-over-ethernet on one of the ports. I have no idea how to do it, so my question is:

1. Does the 2650 support **PoE**?
2. How do I enable it using CLI?

(I know the answer might be very easy, but bear with me).

Comment: Is it a `2600 Series` or a `2600-PWR Series`? You need this one: `HP ProCurve Switch 2650-PWR (J8165A)`.

Comment: It is a J4899B.

Comment: I guess you need to get an inline PoE adapter or a new switch.

Comment: Then again, that switch is quite old, so you'd be better of just getting a newer switch that supports the PoE options you need. PoE is enabled by default on all ports that supports it on HP devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

To recap my and others comments, the HP 2600 series (J4899B in your case) doesn't support PoE, so it can't be enabled. The 2600-PWR series does. On other HP switches that do support PoE, all PoE capable ports are configured to provide PoE out of the box, no extra configuration needed. Your options are either a midspan PoE PSE, or a new switch with PoE support built in.